# Besonderer/besonderen Dank an

Tags: grammatical-case

Ist "besonderer Dank an" schlicht falsch? Ist an dieser Stelle wirklich ein Nominativ möglich? Klingt für mich etwas unflektiert.

Es ist die Übersetzung zu

> Special Thanks To: *Name*

in einer About-Box einer App

Comment: „*Besonderer* Dank gilt Dagobert“ aber *Besonderen* Dank schulde ich Donald. Mehr Kontext, bitte!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Besonderer Dank" ist in diesem Beispiel in der Tat der Nominativ, der Satzteil hinter "an" ist Akkusativ. "Besonderer Dank an Dagobert" ist also korrekt, wenn es um die deutsche Übersetzung von "Special Thanks To: Dagobert" geht.
Sowohl im Original als auch in der Übersetzung fehlt das Prädikat; insofern handelt es sich hier wohlgemerkt nicht um einen vollständigen Satz.